# For/Loop within brackets causing syntax error?

Tags: python

I'm getting an invalid syntax error on the "for account in accounts" loop, why?

Please help, I've been struggling with this for a bit now

```
app.send(
    functions.channels.InviteToChannel(
        channel=app.resolve_peer("xyz123"), 
        users=[
            for account in accounts:
                app.resolve_peer(accounts)
        ]
    )
)
```

Comment: `[app.resolve_peer(accounts) for account in accounts]` is a **list comprehension**, not a for-loop. You're confusing the two. A list comprehension is an expression which returns a list of some sort. A for-loop is a command, not an expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
app.send(
    functions.channels.InviteToChannel(
        channel=app.resolve_peer("xyz123"), 
        users=[
            app.resolve_peer(account) for account in accounts     
        ]
    )
)
```

Comment: You have an extra colon at the end of your comprehension

Comment: Presumably you mean `app.resolve_peer(account)`, not `app.resolve_peer(accounts)`

Comment: Yes that would make more sense :)

Comment: Thank you so much.